# Low gaming performarnce

Tags: games

I recently started with Ubuntu, and i have been facing some problems when it comes to gaming. Im getting very low frame rates on games like CS:GO or Spec Ops The Line, wich are very playable on other OS like Windows 10.
I use an A10-7850K with 8gb of RAM. Other than this im enjoying a lot learning how to get the most out of Ubuntu, so if you can give me some ideas about how to try to fix this issue that would be great! Thank you for your time and have a good day!

Comment: We'll need to know what video driver you're using, what CPU type and speed, how much system RAM, whether the games are Linux native or you're running under Wine -- and probably some other information.

Comment: Thanks for replying! The driver im using is the default ones that comes with the system, i didnt installed anything else. The CPU im using is the A10-7850K 3.7Ghz with the Integrated AMD Radeon R7 Series Graphics, without overclock.  I use 2x4 GB of 2133 Ram. And the game are runing natively by the Steam Client.

Comment: So there's your big difference when comparing with Windows running in the same machine: AMD drivers. The default driver is from the community (open source), it does the job acceptably in most cases but the performance can be the same, at best, and often noticeably worse. Then there's DirectX (Windows only). Games designed around it (and for Windows) always perform better with it. When ported to OpenGL they don't perform as good as with DirectX.

Comment: All current AMD APUs are also supported by `amdgpu-pro`, the new proprietary driver.

Comment: Thanks for replying! And Nvidia do better on the drivers? I will have to upgrade my machine soon, so if Nvidia performs better on Ubuntu i will give it a try. I will try the proprietary drivers and see if they perform better, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

AMD had decided to use AMDGPU-Pro drivers now (fglrx is done). From the [official AMD site](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx):

Do a system update:

> sudo apt update
>
> sudo apt dist-upgrade
>
> sudo reboot

Once you reboot, now check if you have the 'latest' AMDGPU-Pro driver installed:

> dpkg -l amdgpu-pro

It could be that you already have the AMDGPU-Pro driver installed. If it says no packages found, then it's not installed. Then go to the site I linked and follow the instructions to install the latest AMDGPU-Pro package as described there.

There might also be an issue with your CPU downclocking to save energy. That can at times have a performance degrading effect.

Comment: `amdgpu` and `amdgpu-pro` are two different drivers. The former is the default (and open source) for current chips (`radeon` for legacy); `amdgpu-pro` (proprietary) has to be downloaded from AMD and installed.